# Insert into table with multiple select statements in MY SQL

Tags: mysql

I have the result from a query like:

```
+------------------+------------+
| meta_key         | meta_value |
+------------------+------------+
| Destination Name | Shivapuri  |
| Destination Date | 26/03/2012 |
+------------------+------------+
```

I am trying to  write a select statement with the Column name as Destination Name and Destination Date whose respective values are Shivapuri and '26/03/2012'. How is this possible to do with a query in MY SQL?

Comment: This is called a pivot table and has been answered many times before on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Comment: Pivot is rather unneeded, Since by the nature of the structure, there is only going to be one `destination name` and `destination date`.

Comment: How many name and date are going to be there

Comment: What is the full structure of the table?

Answer (score 1):

Something along these lines should do it -

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(meta_key = 'Destination Name', meta_value, NULL)) AS `Destination Name`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(IF(meta_key = 'Destination Date', meta_value, NULL)) AS `Destination Date`
FROM tbl_name
GROUP BY record_identifier
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN meta_key = 'Destination Name' THEN meta_value END) as name,
    (CASE WHEN meta_key = 'Destination Date' THEN meta_value END) as date
FROM `yourtable`
```